# Set size for attachments

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails, attachments

I am working on a custom theme and have generated content with FakerPress to include some uploaded post images.  I want to ensure any image uploaded as an attachment in a post displays in one of the custom sizes instead of its full size, which causes the image to extend beyond the container [See below].

[image]

In my functions file I have the following custom sizes and these work accordingly for thumbnails/featured images:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
//thumbnails & featured images
add_image_size( 'featured-large', 1200, 400, true );
add_image_size( 'full-width', 800, 500);
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'custom_image_size');
    function custom_image_size ( $sizes ) {
        return array_merge( $sizes, array(
            'full-width' => __('Full Width'),
            'featured-large' => __('Featured Large'),
        ));
    }
```

In my single.php template, I am using **the_content();** to get the post content.  Any uploaded/attachment image in the post does not have the srcset in the img tag.  How can I set post images to not exceed their container div/or to be a default size?